# no db connection but no error

Tags: php

here is my db connection code and query code:

```
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('MySQLA22.webcontrolcenter.com', 'shudson', '*******')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('henrybuilt') or die('Could not select database');

$sql = "SELECT ID, vcImageName FROM corp_images WHERE idPage = 6";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error");
```

- There is no 'or die' error upon connecting, selecting, or querying
- There is no error_log file
- The sql query executes if I run it in my sql browser

What is going on???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Are you outputting your SQL query anywhere? Because the code there just runs it.

Comment: @Truth This should be an auto-generated comment every time a post contains the word "mysql_connect"

Comment: @mattedgod: It is, I have it saved in a [Chrome Extension](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and I use it every time

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect to happen versus what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *appears* correct...try adding this adapted code [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to further debug and see what you learn:

```
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$query) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $sql;
   die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['ID'];
    echo $row['vcImageName'];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't throw any errors. The query appears valid. Maybe I'm using it wrong. Added my fetch_assoc code to OP

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, vcImageName FROM corp_images WHERE idPage = 6"
```

Its missing ;

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, vcImageName FROM corp_images WHERE idPage = 6";
```

Comment: Semicolons not needed with `mysql_query`

Comment: The semicolon is missing from the PHP, not the SQL. I assume it's a typo in what he's entered, though, as he claims the code runs.